# How to configure validation for incomming cookies in spring 2.2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Yesterday I switched to Spring 2.2.0-RELEASE.

Sadly shortly after I discovered a breaking change in my integration. 
Currently I am looking for a good work around for it.

In 2.2.0, strict validation for ResponseCookies was introduced, effectively breaking my integration with external services.

Here are slightly obfuscated cookies I receive.

```
Set-Cookie: visid_incap_99025=nMBb1tXkTNusB9ZvFmB60D/pw10AAAAAQUIPAAAAAABzx9/cd4/1jhxcHhOv674S; expires=Thu, 05 Nov 2020 12:11:36 GMT; path=/; Domain=.provider.net
Set-Cookie: nlbi_99025=6FkNJqtqDmAfk5/BL9q5pgAAAABdUK4DN/diqzo8eFw+REau; path=/; Domain=.provider.net
Set-Cookie: incap_ses_457_99025=tLz+ZhxodUxzZqvzpphXBj/pw10AAAAA6RJkHV/vD+s+ZAKC3dwrvw==; path=/; Domain=.provider.net
```

The problematic code is located in the constructor of ResponseCookie of spring-web 5.2.0 package.
This static validation methods throw exception for the Cookies with domain having as the first character `.`.

What is the sensible workaround of that?

Can I configure different decoder with relaxed validation in place?

Can I somehow configure spring WebClient to completely ignore validation?

Forcing the provider to change representation of their Cookies is not within my reach :).

[image: screen shot of the constructor]

Comment: There was an issue open on spring github projects: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23776 But it's closed now. I added a comment anyway hoping they would reconsider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fixed from version 2.2.2.

[Relevant Github issue.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23924)